# How many different matrices $A$ and $B$ are possible such that product $AB$ is defined?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations

Two matrices $A$ and $B$ have in total $6$ different elements (none repeated). How many different matrices $A$ and $B$ are possible such that product $AB$ is defined?

**My attempts**

> **$1^{st} Attempt$**

Considering that there are $6$ different elements in both $A$ and $B$ matrices, i.e., there are total $12$ elements.
[image]

> **$2^{nd} Attempt$**

[image]

Comment: What are the elements of the matrices? Reals, integers, ...? Also, the matrices have in total $6$ elements or each matrix has $6$ elements?

Comment: I am also in the same confusion that the matrices have in total 6 elements or each matrix has 6 elements?

Comment: The statement says "in total". Where did you find this problem?

Comment: This question is given in my textbook

Comment: I would interpret in total to mean that adding the number of elements in matrix $A$ to the number of elements in matrix $B$ yields $6$.

Comment: The second solution you posted is correct.  If it is from a solution key, is there some aspect of the solution that you do not understand?  If it is your own work, you should type it using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) since images cannot be searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer was revised in response to the posting of the solution.  I initially overlooked that the product of a matrix with two elements and a matrix with four elements could be formed in four ways.  The method in the posted solution is preferable to the one written below.*

Your strategy is correct.  However, saying that matrices $A$ and $B$ have in total six elements means that adding the number of elements in matrix $A$ to the number of elements in matrix $B$ yields $6$.

We can partition $6$ in the following ways:
\begin{align*}
6 & = 1 + 5\\
  & = 2 + 4\\
  & = 3 + 3
\end{align*}
Thus, we can form products if we can find a matrix with one element that can be multiplied by a matrix with five elements, a matrix with two elements that can be multiplied by a matrix with four elements, or a matrix with three elements that can be multiplied by a matrix with three elements.  In each case, we can satisfy the requirement that the number of columns in $A$ is equal to the number of rows in $B$ in two ways.

\begin{array}{c c c}
A & B & AB\\ \hline
1 \times 1 & 1 \times 5 & 1 \times 5\\
5 \times 1 & 1 \times 1 & 5 \times 1\\
1 \times 2 & 2 \times 2 & 1 \times 2\\
2 \times 2 & 2 \times 1 & 2 \times 1\\
4 \times 1 & 1 \times 2 & 4 \times 2\\
2 \times 1 & 1 \times 4 & 2 \times 4\\ 
1 \times 3 & 3 \times 1 & 1 \times 1\\
3 \times 1 & 1 \times 3 & 3 \times 3
\end{array}
Since there are $8$ possible ways to form the product and the matrices $A$ and $B$ can be populated in $6!$ different ways by $6$ distinct elements in each case, the number of different matrices $A$ and $B$ that can be constructed so that the product is defined is $8 \cdot 6!$.